# Insert into UITableView with animation?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios4, uiviewcontroller, uitableview

I have a View that I want to display a UITableView in and animate to add rows. In my .m, I have it set as a UIViewController with the UITableView subclasses. I have my dataSource and delegate linked up with my File's owner.

Since when trying to call something like this won't work: `[self.tableView reloadData]'`, I created a UITableView IBOutlet to do this - `theTableView`.

When trying to call to add objects like this:

```
NSArray *insertIndexPaths = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                             [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0],
                             [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:0],
                             [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:2 inSection:0],
                             nil];
[theTableView beginUpdates];
[theTableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:insertIndexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
[theTableView endUpdates];
```

It launches, but nothing happens when the viewDidLoad was called. I can't make it a UITableViewController because I have many other items in there.

Sorry if my lingo sounds a bit off - I'm a noobie at this. Any help is appreciated!

Coulton

Comment: How are you adding the UITableView to your view?

Comment: I am populating it with a NSMutableArray.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing that you have a broken connection to your UITableView outlet in Interface Builder.

Comment: And you're synthesizing the property and calling self.theTableView right?